# How to customize the SearchDialog in android

Tags: java, android, search-dialog

When SearchDialog is called, it have a white background.

There's a way to change the background color, and also remove the up button with the icon near to it?

I don't use the SearchView, i use the search dialog because i need it also in android pre 3.0

Thanks